# Find an implicit solution to $y ^ { \prime } ( x ) = \frac { x ^ { 3 } } { 2 y \sqrt { 1 + y ^ { 2 } } }$

Tags: integration

$y ^ { \prime } ( x ) = \frac { x ^ { 3 } } { 2 y \sqrt { 1 + y ^ { 2 } } }$

$\frac { d y } { d x } = \frac { x ^ { 3 } } { 2 y \sqrt { 1 + y ^ { 2 } } }$

$\frac { d x } { d y } = \frac { 2 y \sqrt { 1 + y ^ { 2 } } } { x ^ { 3 } }$

$\int x ^ { 3 } d x = 2 \int y \left( 1 + y ^ { 2 } \right) ^ { 1 / 2 } d y$

R.H.S.

$\int y \sqrt { 1 + y ^ { 2 } } d y$

let $u = 1 + y ^ { 2 }$

$ d u = 2 y d y $

$ \frac { d u } { 2 } = y d y $

$\int y \sqrt { 1 + y ^ { 2 } } d y$

$\int \sqrt { 1 + y ^ { 2 } } y d y$

$\int \frac { \sqrt { u } } { 2 } d u$

$\frac { 1 } { 2 } \int \sqrt { u } d u$

$= \frac { 1 } { 2 } \left[ \frac { 2 u ^ { 3 / 2 } } { 3 } \right]$

$= \frac { u ^ { 3 / 2 } } { 3 } = \frac { 1 } { 3 } \left( 1 + y ^ { 2 } \right) ^ { 3 / 2 } \ldots 1$

$\int x ^ { 3 } d y = 2 \int y \left( 1 + y ^ { 2 } \right) ^ { 1 / 2 } d y$

$\frac { x ^ { 4 } } { 4 } + c = 2 \left[ 1 / 3 \left( 1 + y ^ { 2 } \right) ^ { 3 / 2 } \right]$

$\frac { x ^ { 4 } } { 4 } + c = \frac { 2 } { 3 } \left( 1 + y ^ { 2 } \right) ^ { 3 / 2 }$

cant finish it , or maybe my working is wrong ?

Comment: It looks like you already have an implicit solution.  Remember that implicit means you do not need to isolate the variable $y$.

Comment: SO its done even with the + C ?

Comment: In order to find the value of $c$, you need to be provided an initial condition.

Comment: You cannot find an explicit formula without an initial condition.

Comment: If I may ask , is my working correct ? (P.S. took me ages to put on latex inorder to ask this question)

Comment: so explicit solution = particular solution ?

Comment: Not quite.  Explicit just means of the form $y(x) = ...$.  For example, the implicit solution with initial condition $y(0) = 0$ would be $(1/4)x^4+2/3 = 2/3(1+y^2)^{3/2}.$

Comment: You can get an explicit solution where y is a function of x and c.  Is that what you are looking for?  The original question was for an implicit solution - that is what you have already.